# Unique Permutations of a Labeled Graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Given a connected graph with $v$ vertices and $e$ edges, how would I go about determining how many unique permutations of vertices and edges I could have?

So far, I have only been able to figure out how to solve for $e = v - 1$ and complete graphs.  However as soon as the graph starts to get cycles at $e = v$, everything I can think of goes out the window, so I'm at a bit of a loss for how to solve this problem.  I've been wracking my brain with this for the last couple days, so I'd be very grateful for a little help.

By hand, I've been able to obtain:

$f(Vertices,Edges) -> Permutation$

$f(2 , 1) = 1$

$f(3 , 2) = 3$

$f(3 , 3) = 1$

$f(4 , 3) = 16$

$f(4 , 4) = 15$

$f(4 , 5) = 6$

$f(4 , 6) = 1$

$f(5 , 4) = 125$

$f(5 , 10) = 1$

$f(n , n - 1) = n^{n-2}$

$f(n , \frac{n^2 - n}{2}) = 1$

However I'd like to be able to obtain the number of unique permutations mathematically.

If anything was unclear, please let me know and I'd be happy to try to clear it up.

Comment: When you say *unique* permutations, do you mean *distinct* permutations?

Comment: The question as stated is imcomprehensible. From your table of values, I'm pretty that what you really want is the number of labeled connected graphs with $v$ vertices and $e$ edges.

Comment: Apologies.  I'm not entirely familiar with the subject (if that wasn't clear, rofl).  Anyways, @Sammy Black, what I mean, is given any arbitrary labeled  graph, I need to find all permutations which are different.  That is to say, the graphs of {[a, b] [b, c] [c, d]} and {[d, c] [c, b] [b, a]} are equivalent. And

Comment: @bof, what I really want is the function f which takes those two values, determines every possible graph that can be created using them, and then determines how many unique (distinct? See above) permutations there are in total.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A008406 is what you want, I think.

Comment: Oops, sorry. As bof says, it's labelled graphs you are asking about, so https://oeis.org/A062734 is more like it. f(4, 3) = 16, f(5, 4) = 125 as you have, but also f(5, 6)  = 205 and (6, 9) = 4945.

Comment: @gilleain that is in fact EXACTLY what I'm looking for.  I'd love to learn more about the theory about how that solution came about if you happen to know anything about it.  But yeah, that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Responding to

> given any arbitrary labeled graph, I need to find all permutations which are different

The number of labeled graphs isomorphic to a given $n$-vertex graph $G$ is given by the [orbit-stabilizer theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbit-stabilizer_theorem_and_Burnside.27s_lemma).  It is:
$$
\frac{n!}{|\mathrm{aut}(G)|}
$$
where $\mathrm{aut}(G)$ is the automorphism group of the graph $G$.  In general, finding $|\mathrm{aut}(G)|$ requires computation (i.e., there's no succinct formula for it).

In the listed numbers, you appear to be summing this value over isomorphism classes of connected $n$-vertex $e$-edge graphs.